# Slim PHP REST API not fetching data in production server, works in localhost

Tags: php, mysql, rest, slim

I have a simple Slim PHP REST api which works great on my local server, but when I pushed it to a shared hosting server it does not fetch the data. My limited plan does not give me SSH access to the database so it is difficult to run tests, but this is what I have tracked so far...

Here is a test api endpoint:

```
$app->get('/test', function() use($app) {
    $app->response->setStatus(200);
    if($db = getDB()){
      echo "connected<br>";
    } else{
      echo "not connected<br>";
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM artists";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    if($stmt){
      echo "statement true<br>";
    } else{
    echo "statement not true<br>";
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    if($stmt->fetch()){
      echo "executed";
    }else{
      echo "not executed";
    }
});
```

This gives me an output of:
'connected'
'statement true'
'not executed'.

I am able to run queries from the phpMyAdmin dashboard successfully. In the webpage, the rest api is working fine and returning a 'No match found' message implying that the functions are working, but the data set is empty. I do not know which direction to look to find why no records are being returned?

In the complete data functions:

```
    $error = array('error' => 'No match found');

    // fetch data into array
    $i = 0;
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $data[$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }

    // return data
    if($data) {
        $app->response->setStatus(200);
        $app->response()->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    } else {
        $app->response->setStatus(200);
        $app->response()->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        echo json_encode($error);
    }
```

I am new to PHP so any advice on how to trouble shoot, log, or otherwise trace the issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhhh... I found it! The problem was not with the php, but with the sql. Apparently, sql statements are case insensitive on my local machine (mac), but case sensitive on Linux servers. In the DB the table name is `Artists` where in the code above I had `artists`.

So the correction is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM artists";
```

Becomes:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Artists";
```